# DB2: How can I avoid specifying the fully qualified identifier and only use the tablename?

Tags: sql, database, db2

In a DB2 database while selecting record, why is the fully qualified identifier (schemaname.tablename) required? How can I only use the tablename in my queries?

Example:
Schema name is s1.

```
select * from s1.tablename;
```

I want to issue my query like this:

```
select * from tablename;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can. Execute a `SET SCHEMA s1` to specify that your tablename will be from "s1".

Here is the documentation on [SET SCHEMA](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001016.html).

```
SET SCHEMA s1;
select * from tablename;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on iseries (old AS400) you can use set schema of course or specify your libs into your libl with [ADDLIBLE](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_i5_54/cl/addlible.htm) command, or [CHGLIBL](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r1/ic2924/index.htm?info/cl/chglibl.htm) command